# How to build the following sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I have 4 table.

```
1.Category Table.
  Fields : Id , Name ,  Description
  Data   : 1    School  This is school


2.CategoryMeta Table
  Field : Id , CategoryId , FieldName
  Data  : 1        1        Phone
          2        1        Address

3.Object Table
  Field : Id , CategoryId , ojectName ,   ObjectDesc
           1        1        ABC School   This is a good school

4.ObjectMeta Table
  Fields : Id , CategoryId , ObjectId , CategoryMetaId , FieldValue
  Data   : 1        1           1             1          919475864253
           2        1           1             2          ABC Road.India
```

I want the following output from the query.I set the category Id as a parameter

```
ObjectId  ObjectName  ObjectDesc                Phone        Address
  1        ABC School  This is a good school   919475864253  ABC Road.India
```

I need a list of objects.Can any one help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried to write this query at all yourself? Can you explain how you are trying to relate the tables to get to the final result set?

Comment: setting this up in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and posting a link will go a long way to help getting your question answered.

Comment: working through this query will let you appreciate why you dont do a schema like this - this is a better structure for OOP languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to JOIN the tables and use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to convert the rows of values into columns:

```
select o.id,
  o.ojectname,
  o.objectdesc,
  max(case when cm.fieldname = 'Phone' then om.fieldvalue end) Phone,
  max(case when cm.fieldname = 'Address' then om.fieldvalue end) Address
from object o
left join objectmeta om
  on o.id = om.objectid
left join categorymeta cm
  on om.categorymetaid = cm.id
group by o.id, o.ojectname, o.objectdesc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e920/2). Depending on your RDBMS that you are using you could create a dynamic SQL version of this what will get the list of `fieldnames` based on what is stored in your database.

Comment: Thanks..It's working..Thanks a lot for help.But in my case Phone , address those are also not static.Those are depend on the value of the categoryMeta table. Thanks a lot for your help.I accept your answer..

Comment: @amitghosh What database are you using?  I can provide a dynamic version but the code is based on the database.

Comment: I am using mysql..But I need to write this query in codeigniter..

Answer (score 0):

This is the query, but your schema need some Improvements.

```
select ph.*, om2.FieldValue as Address from
(
    select o.id as ObjectId, o.ObjectName, o.ObjectDesc,om1.FieldValue as Phone
    from object o
    join ObjectMeta om1 on o.id = om1.ObjectID
    where om1.CategoryMetaID = 1
) ph
join ObjectMeta om2 on ph.ObjectId = om2.ObjectID
where om2.CategoryMetaID = 2
```

Comment: is om1 and om2 both are ObjectMeta ?

Comment: And the address and phone are also not static...it can be any thing for any category.

Comment: sorry it's not working..it's giving 0 row as result.